# An error occured (CUDA)

Tags: nvidia, package-management, cuda

I installed few days ago Ubuntu 18.04, I would like to use tensorflow on python. After some errors in the spyder console I thought it would have been necessary to download CUDA. The errors persisted by the way, and I thought that possibly there was no supporting between the two version I had, like suggested [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26209).

So I tried to downgrade both tf and CUDA, like suggested I tried to have tf 1.13.1, and CUDA 10.0. However, I think I made a little mess in the downgrading of CUDA; and now I have this error notification:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: "Error: BrokenCount>0". This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

I tried to do `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` and the finals lines I have in the terminal are:

```
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Before that I tried to eliminate all the mess I made downloading CUDA, using:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*
```

but I think it didn't worked as hoped...

Any suggestions?

I was thinking about deleting everything with "cuda" in its name. But it seems both brutal (I could delete something I actually need) and maybe not efficient (maybe some stuff cannot be deleted this way).

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved.

I manually deleted files named in the errors, I cleaned the cache, and I ran [this](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73#file-cuda_10-0_installation_on_ubuntu_18-04-L34) which both deletes and reinstalls. I think the first manual action was actually the one which solved the error.